# Error en el submenu solo al acceder desde el celular

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

Buen dia, se me genera un error o falla en la siguiente pagina en construcción:

http://www.graficaelpunto.com/web/

Cuando accedo desde un teléfono (deben acceder desde uno ya que en pc éste error no se genera) el menú funciona bien (se visualiza), la pestaña "cumples y eventos" abre bien, pero al abrir la pestaña "otros servicios" (estando abierta la de cumples) se da como una doble selección y redirige a la sección "otros servicios" sin dejarme visualizar las opciones del submenu. Esta falla solo la realiza si esta abierto el submenu de cumples, y si apunto a la "O" de OTROS SERVICIOS, despliega el submenu sin problemas....

¿Qué puede ser lo que me crea la falla? 
ahi paso el codigo html, css y js del menu:

```
<nav id="ioMenu">
        <figure id="showMenu" class="ioMenuMovil" onClick="displayMenu()"><img src="imagenes/menu.png" alt="menu"></figure>
        <div id="cardMenu">
            <figure id="hideMenu" class="ioMenuMovil exit" onClick="displayMenu()"><img src="imagenes/exit.png" alt="exit"></figure>
            <figure id="logoMenu"><img src="imagenes/descarga.png" alt="logo diseñadora"></figure>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="diseño Grafico.html">DISEÑO GRAFICO</a></li>
                <li><a href="bolsas de papel.html">BOLSAS DE PAPEL IMPRESAS</a></li>
                <li><a href="carteleria.html">CARTELERIA</a></li>
                <li id="cYE"><a href="#">CUMPLES Y EVENTOS <span>"flecha"</span></a>
                    <ul id="subMenuCyE">
                        <p>Diseños personalizados de</p>
                        <li><a href="cumples y eventos.html">SOUVENIRS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="cumples y eventos.html">TARJETAS </a></li>
                        <li><a href="cumples y eventos.html">PINS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="cumples y eventos.html">BANDERINES</a></li>
                        <li><a href="cumples y eventos.html">MESAS DULCES</a></li>
                        <li><a href="cumples y eventos.html">BOLCITAS PARA CARAMELOS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="cumples y eventos.html">CAJITAS</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li id="otrosServicios"><a href="#">OTROS SERVICIOS <span>"flecha"</span></a>
                    <ul id="subMenuOS">
                        <li><a href="otros servicios.html">PAPELERIA COMERCIAL</a></li>
                        <li><a href="otros servicios.html">MANEJO DE REDES</a></li>
                        <li><a href="otros servicios.html">TARJETAS Y SOUVENIRS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="otros servicios.html">DISEÑO WEB</a></li>
                        <li><a href="otros servicios.html">ESTAMPADOS Y BORDADOS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="otros servicios.html">SUBLIMACION</a></li>
                        <li><a href="otros servicios.html">PINS PUBLICITARIOS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="otros servicios.html">IMPRESION FOTOGRAFICA</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="formularioContacto.html">CONTACTANOS</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div><a id="contact_button" href="formularioContacto.html"></a></div>
    </nav>
```

y el css

```
/*----------------------------MENU--------------*/
nav .ioMenuMovil{
width: 150px;
height:30px;
margin: 0 0 0 8px;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 2px;
display: inline-block;
cursor: pointer;
}

nav .ioMenuMovil img{
height: 75%;
padding-top: 4px;
}


/*-----------------TARJETA EXIT------------------*/
nav #cardMenu{
background: #fff;
width: 78%;
max-width: 250px;
position: absolute;
padding-bottom: 30px;
top: 0;
border-right: 3px solid #A7A7A7;
border-bottom: 3px solid #A7A7A7;
display: none;
z-index: 999;
}
nav #cardMenu #hideMenu img{
height: 24px;
}

nav #cardMenu #logoMenu{
margin-bottom: 30px;
margin-top: 50px;
}

nav #cardMenu #logoMenu img{
width: 40%; 
position: relative;
left: 30%;
}

nav #cardMenu ul{
position: relative;
margin-left: 20%;
}

nav #cardMenu ul li{
position: relative;
list-style: none;
}

nav #cardMenu ul li a{
text-decoration: none;
color: #605F5F;
font-size: 1.0em;
padding: 10px 20px 10px 0px;
display: block;
}

/*----------------SUBMENUS-----------------------*/

nav#ioMenu #cardMenu ul li ul#subMenuCyE{
width: 90%;
font-size: 1em;
position: relative;
margin: 0 ;
top: 0;
left: 15px;
display: none;
}

nav#ioMenu #cardMenu ul li ul#subMenuOS{
width: 90%;
display: none;
position: relative;
margin: 0;
top: 0;
left: 15px;
}

nav#ioMenu #cardMenu ul li#otrosServicios:hover>ul{
display: block;
}

nav#ioMenu #cardMenu ul li#cYE:hover>ul{
display: block;
}
```

y el js es:

```
function displayMenu(){
var display;
var cardMenu = document.getElementById("cardMenu");
display = cardMenu.style.display;
if(display == "none"|| display.length == 0){ /*|| display.length == 0  detecta el estado del menu*/
    cardMenu.style.display = "block";
}
else{
    cardMenu.style.display = "none";
}

function navSection(nav){
var search;

document.getElementById("cardMenu").style.display = "none";//////////*CIERRA MENU AL SELECCIONAE LA SECCION*/

for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    search = document.getElementById(sections[i]);
    search.style.display = "none";

    if(sections[i] == nav){
         search.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

}

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola, te recomiendo que añadas la parte de tu código donde crees que se genera el error para que alguien pueda ayudarte.

Comment: Habría que ver el javascript asociado `onClick="displayMenu()"`/ `onClick="navSection('home')"` tal vez falte un prevent default o se pueda armar de manera diferente.